# Solidity function doesn't return a variable

Tags: solidity

here is my function from sol contract

```
 function swapExactInputMultihop(uint amountIn, address importToken1,address importToken2,address importToken3,uint fee1,uint fee2, uint fee3)
        external
        returns (uint)
    
       
        TransferHelper.safeApprove(importToken1, address(swapRouter), amountIn);
        
        
        ISwapRouter.ExactInputParams memory params = ISwapRouter
            .ExactInputParams({
                path: abi.encodePacked(
                    importToken1,
                    uint24(fee1),
                    importToken2,
                    uint24(fee2),
                    importToken3,
                    uint24(fee3),
                    importToken1

                ),
                recipient: msg.sender,
                deadline: block.timestamp,
                amountIn: amountIn,
                amountOutMinimum: 0
            });
            
        uint amountOut = swapRouter.exactInput(params);
        console.log("HEEELP",amountOut);
        return amountOut;

        
    }
```

In JavaScript I'm calling this function and I hope to get `amountOut`

```
arbitrage = await swapExamples.swapExactInputMultihop(amountIn,importToken1,importToken2,importToken3,fee1,fee2,fee3)
console.log(arbitrage)
```

but I'm receiving the whole data

```
{
  hash: '0x97668c1ef43c53e2126e645f8224fe68188be2cb024c0e0e5deb722164c8491f',
  type: 2,
  accessList: [],
  blockHash: '0xcb381a0c0d855f60695f4decc2b18efa9ab1f0939b9634812f8ffd18d0ce406c',
  blockNumber: 15466768,
  transactionIndex: 0,
  confirmations: 1,
  from: '0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266',
  gasPrice: BigNumber { value: "6285584267" },
  maxPriorityFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "1000000000" },
  maxFeePerGas: BigNumber { value: "11571168534" },
  gasLimit: BigNumber { value: "29026840" },
  to: '0xFD2Cf3b56a73c75A7535fFe44EBABe7723c64719',
  value: BigNumber { value: "0" },
  nonce: 289,
  data: '0xddae289800000000000000000000000000000000000000000000152d02c7e14af68000000000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb48000000000000000000000000c02aaa39b223fe8d0a0e5c4f27ead9083c756cc200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000640000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bb80000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000bb8',
  r: '0xdbcb97e9e2678b6f4614950351c220abdd8692aa12957953d3409d31181908c1',
  s: '0x0f00c2d48f721c265fd68c921f2f3648559a439f0af206e5c9bc464dfa13abe3',
  v: 1,
  creates: null,
  chainId: 31337,
  wait: [Function (anonymous)]
}
```

How can I get amountOut?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get return values for non view/pure functions when you make calls off-chain.

You have to either put the return value in an event, and read the event after you make the call, or use ethers.js `callStatic`. This queries the node for what the return value would be if you made the call, but *doesn't actually make the call* or change state. This is treated as a view function.

You could do this:

```
// make the static view call
let arbitrage = await swapExamples.callStatic.swapExactInputMultihop(amountIn,importToken1,importToken2,importToken3,fee1,fee2,fee3)


// make the real call
let tx = await swapExamples.swapExactInputMultihop(amountIn,importToken1,importToken2,importToken3,fee1,fee2,fee3)

connsole.log(arbitrage)
```

Comment: Thanks for such a good explanation. It helps me a lot

Comment: amountOut 99164969206333049048119 without callStatic
amountOut 98807153753175904679967 with callStatic . So in the first case it's a result from real transaction. And the second one is just theoretical possibility? And with some coins the difference is huge.